# Centered oval shape with repeated pattern on either side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

I have an image that isn't as big as all screen sizes, yet I want it to be displayed on screens with whatever width by adding a repeated pattern on either side. I can of course make the image a lot wider but that would cause the page to load a lot slower as well.

It's a bit hard to explain by text so here are some images and the [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7n06und5/).

```css
#layer_top {
    background:url("http://puu.sh/cajm0/c0c2cc9475.jpg") repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:136px;
}

#layer_transition {
    width:100%;
    height:36px;
    margin-top:-36px;
    background-image:url("http://puu.sh/cajG0/2768274649.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

#layer_bottom {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:url("http://puu.sh/cajmN/9b1e9ef79f.jpg") repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="layer_top"></div>
<div id="layer_transition"></div>
<div id="layer_bottom"></div>
```

**Result:**
[image: Result]

**Wanted Result:**
[image: Wanted Result]

Comment: Can't you change the curvy grey one to be wider by adding straight grey lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that by adding a pseudo-element to the top layer which is formed as ellipse and it's positioned with the respect of the layer.

Then simply apply the same background image to both, layer and the pseudo-element:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7n06und5/6/)**

```css
#layer_top, #layer_top:after {
   background:url("http://puu.sh/cajm0/c0c2cc9475.jpg") repeat;
}

#layer_top { width:100%; height:136px; position: relative; }

#layer_top:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 500px; height: 100%;
    left: 0; right: 0; top: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

---

You could also use `clip` to cut the extra part of the oval shape.

Comment: Here is the **[updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/7n06und5/12/)** which uses [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip). This *may* give a better effect.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a different solution but it might just work:

Why don't you replace the mask image? So instead of overlaying this gray thing, make an overlay for the purprle one. If you position that centered against the top of the grey area, you've got the same result/

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is with the div elements you created its hard to get it work.

An easy solution is to use for the bottom part 3 diffrent divs.

```
<div id="side_layer"></div>
<div id="layer_bottom"></div>
<div id="side_layer"></div>
```

I created a simple jsfiddle for you: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7n06und5/5/)

It does work responsive until 500px width. 
You could simply add a media query and hide the right and left layer then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this it is easy.

Add CSS class to body or create parent div above body and style it.

Working Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7n06und5/11/

```
     .parent {
    margin:0;
    background:url("http://puu.sh/cajm0/c0c2cc9475.jpg") repeat;
    width:100%;
}

#layer_top {
    background:url("http://puu.sh/cajm0/c0c2cc9475.jpg") repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:136px;
}

#layer_transition {
    width:100%;
    height:36px;
    margin-top:-36px;
    background-image:url("http://puu.sh/cajG0/2768274649.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

#layer_bottom {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:url("http://puu.sh/cajmN/9b1e9ef79f.jpg") repeat;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<body class="parent">
<div id="layer_top">

</div>
<div id="layer_transition">

</div>
<div id="layer_bottom">

</div>

</body>
```

**Hope it helps you!**

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with `css border-raidus`

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header{
    background:url(http://puu.sh/cajm0/c0c2cc9475.jpg) repeat-x;
    //height:75px;
    //width:100%; 
    padding:3% 15%;
}
#inner{
    background:url(http://puu.sh/cajm0/c0c2cc9475.jpg) repeat-x;
    height:75px;
    width:100%;    
    border-radius:0 0 50% 50%;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nzx7q88p/)